# Minecraft 1.10 /testfor player manually breaking a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if there was a way to test for players breaking a specific block, such as dirt.  After they break the block, they die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an objective of the type you want, for example:

```
/scoreboard objectives add BreakDirt stat.mineBlock.minecraft.dirt
```

Then, on a clock and in this order, have the following commands:

```
/kill @a[score_BreakDirt_min=1]
/scoreboard players set @a[score_BreakDirt_min=1] BreakDirt 0
```

The first command kills anyone who has broken dirt, the second command sets their score back to 0 so they don't die repeatedly.

Comment: Am I able to put multiple objectives into one command?

Comment: @ReaLord Yes. For example: `@a[score_SCORE1_min=1,score_SCORE2_min=3,score_SCORE3=0]`